# Having trouble running a python program on CMD on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, cmd

Here is the program. It works great on the IDLE but, it crashes after asking if you know the password length. I can't seem to figure out want i'm missing. I would love any help.

```
import itertools
import string
import sys, os, cmd

from datetime import datetime
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
passwordstried = 0


numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0,]
#symbols = [
lowercaseletters =  ["q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l","g","h","j","k","l","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"]
uppercaseletters = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]


stuff = lowercaseletters + uppercaseletters + numbers

if (input("Do you have the length of the password?") == 'y'):
    lengthstartingvalue = int(input("Password length: "))
else:
    lengthstartingvalue = 0


starttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(starttime)





starttime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
for L in range(lengthstartingvalue, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(stuff, L):
        print(subset)
        passwordstried = passwordstried + 1
    if (L>lengthstartingvalue-1):
        break

endtime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
elapsed = datetime.strptime(endtime, FMT) - datetime.strptime(starttime, FMT)
print ('Time elapsed:',elapsed)
print ('Passwords tried:',passwordstried)
```

Comment: How does it crash? Can you post the exception?

Comment: That's the thing. I can't even see what's going on.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Traceback? It looks like you are using Python 3.x. Is the problem the windows disappears? If so, just add `input()` as the last statement so that the window stays open until you hit <enter>

Comment: @Conner Can you clarify which version of Python you are using?

Comment: Np. It's Python 3.3. Also tried the input. Still crashes after asking if I know how long the password is.

Comment: Run this program from an already-open command prompt (under Accessories) and see if you can give us more information.

Comment: @275365 You were right with your suggestion (though off with the Python version), consider undeleting your answer - I'll happily yield the accept to you if OP will do it. (I posted this earlier, but got your userid wrong - that's the problem with all those numbers :)

Comment: @Levon Thanks for your generosity, but your answer works well. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@275365 was right, you should use

`if (raw_input("Do you have the length of the password?") == 'y'):`

instead of

`if (input("Do you have the length of the password?") == 'y'):`

Using `input()` leads to a crash,

```
In [11]: run tt.py
Do you have the length of the password?y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files (x86)\ipython-0.12.1\IPython\utils\py3compat.py in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    166             else:
    167                 filename = fname
--> 168             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    169     else:
    170         def execfile(fname, *where):

D:\Users\sp\Desktop\tt.py in <module>()
     16 stuff = lowercaseletters + uppercaseletters + numbers
     17
---> 18 if (input("Do you have the length of the password?") == 'y'):
     19     lengthstartingvalue = int(input("Password length: "))
     20 else:

D:\Users\sp\Desktop\<string> in <module>()

NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

while changing it to `raw_input()` runs to completion without a crash.

Comment: The OP claims to be using Python 3.3. Unless there's a problem with multiple Python versions the OP hasn't realized (which may be the case), this isn't the answer.

Comment: Use of the print() would indicate that i'm using 3.3 I just uninstalled 2.7 to make sure it wasn't this.

Comment: @Conner What happens if you change the `input()` to `raw_input()`? I ran this w/o a crash under 3.2.3 (the only 3.x version I have access to right now).

Answer (score 1):

It seems you may be running a different version of IDLE than you are coding in. If I understand correctly, raw_input() works on your CMD but breaks in IDLE, while input() works in IDLE and breaks in CMD. You may need to download the proper version of IDLE for Python 3, or if you have it you are just accessing the one for Python 2.

Otherwise, it could be a problem with your Path variable in Windows. In System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> Path  - which needs to be set to your Python 3.3 installation.

To me, it seems like your Path may still be stuck on the previous installation.